# How to handle multi line fixed length file with BeanIO

Tags: etl, bean-io

I'm very new to BeanIO, it is solving most of my problems but I'm unable to figure out how to solve this one:

I have a multiline fixed width file in the following format:

```
BBB001     000          000000
BBB555     001          George
BBB555     002          London
BBB555     003          UK
BBB555     999          000000
BBB555     001          Jean
BBB555     002          Paris
BBB555     003          France
BBB555     004          Europe
BBB555     999          000000
BBB999     000          000000
```

Basically there is a header and footer which I can easily read because they are well defined. However a single record is actually on multiple lines and end of the record is the line that that has 999 in the middle ( there is no other information on that line). I was wondering what should my xml be or what classes do I need to override so I can properly read this type of format.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [lineContinuationCharacter](http://www.beanio.org/2.0/docs/reference/index.html#FixedLengthStreamFormat) property, as described in the BeanIO documentation. It probably has to be configured as a carriage return and line feed.

Try something like this:

```
<beanio xmlns="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.beanio.org/2012/03 http://www.beanio.org/2012/03/mapping.xsd">

  <stream name="s1" format="fixedlength" lineContinuationCharacter="&#x10;&#x13;">
    <!-- record layout... -->
  </stream>

</beanio>
```

Note that I haven't tested this, but according to the documentation this should work.

Comment: This works well if you have a single character. In my case I would need a way to identify that anything different from 999 and that is not an available option.